# Inserting Data into Linked Repositories in ATG

Tags: atg

I have a requirement in which I have two tables `employee` in `ABC` repository
and `address_details` in `XYZ` repository.

One column of `employee` has a foreign key reference to `address_details`.

Here, I am having the `primaryKey` for `address_details` and with that `primaryKey`
reference I have to insert my data in `employee`.

So my RDF goes something like this:

RDF 1: (Repository1 : `ABC`)

```
<item-descriptor name=”employee” >
 <table name=”employee”>
   <property name=”empId” data-type=”string” column-name=”emp_id”
     required=”true”/>
   <property name=”address” column-name=”address_id” item-type=”address”
     repository=”XYZ” required=”true”/>
 </table>
</item-descriptor>
```

RDF 2: (Repsitory2 : `XYZ`)

```
<item-descriptor name=”address” >
  <table name=”address_details”>
    <property name=”addressId” data-type=”string” column-name=”address_id”/>
    <property name=”streetName” column-name=”street_name” data-type=”string”/>
    <property name=”city” column-name=”city” data-type=”string” />
  </table>
</item-descriptor>
```

I have all the addresses stored in table `address_details`. And I have to
map `employee` to these addresses.

The way which I am trying here is fetching the `RepostoryItem` of `Address`
first, then setting the property-type `address` of `employee` and adding it
into `employee` table. This works.

But I want to insert the `employee` data in one call alone?

Any suggestions on how can I do that using `RepositoryItem` or
`MutableRepositoryItem`?

Comment: Why do you need to associate in one call? It stands to reason that if you want to associate the two you must first look up the items you want to association and then perform the association. There's nothing wrong with first doing the necessary lookups and then updating the employee item when you have found the appropriate address item.

Answer (score 0):

By insert in one call, I'm assuming you mean you want to commit all of the inserts atomically.  There is no mechanism to do multiple inserts in one SQL statement -- you'll have to call MutableRepository.addItem() once for each item you have created.  The following code will allow you to wrap your repository work in a transaction, so that the data is all committed at once.

```
TransactionManager tm = ...
TransactionDemarcation td = new TransactionDemarcation ();
try {
  try {
    td.begin(tm);

    // Create all items and call MutableRepository.addItem() for each of them.
  }
  finally {
    td.end();
  }
}
catch (TransactionDemarcationException exc) {
  logError(exc);
}
```